# Linq to SQL mapping data without a DataContext

Tags: linq-to-sql, audit

Is it possible to access Linq to SQL mapping data without a DataContext instance?

I ask because I am writing some audit data generation code that will only trigger for some entities and some entity columns. I would like to fix up this meta data in a static constructor prior to any Linq DB access.

For example from a performance perspective it would be preferable to discover the primary key column of an entity just once instead of triggering the following code for each changed entity in the ChangeSet:

```
var metaTable = context.Mapping.GetTable(entityType);
var key = (PropertyInfo)metaTable.RowType.DataMembers.Single(
                   md => md.IsPrimaryKey).Member;
```

Prior to calling:

```
key.GetValue(entity, null),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you don't need an instance of `DataContext`, only the type.

```
MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();
MetaModel mapping = mappingSource.GetModel(typeof(MyDataContext));
```

Here I'm using `AttributeMappingSource`, you could use `XmlMappingSource` or other implementations of `MappingSource`.

Comment: Excellent news. Since I just dragged table names onto the Visual Studio Linq model window I assume an AttributeMappingSource mapping source is all I need?

Comment: Yes, the VS designer uses attributes.